# How to put numbers in ascending, return them in a tuple, and add another argument.(Python)

Tags: python, tuples

Function signature :

```
def rank3(x,y,z,    ascending=True)
```

Given   three   integers,   return  them    in  order   in  a   tuple of
length  three.  An  optional    fourth  argument    (ascending) states  whether output  should  be  sorted ascending    (argument   is  True)   or  descending  (argument   is  False).

Examples:

```
§ rank3(5,  3,  4) → (3,4,5)

§ rank3(5,  3,  4,  False) → (5,4,3)

§ rank3(6,  8,  6) → (6,6,8)
```

This is my code so far:

```
x = num1 #your first input

y = num2 #your second input

z = num3 #your third input

a = [x, y, z] #your list of inputs 

b = [] #your sorted list

def rank3(x,y,z,    ascending=True):

    while a: # your sort function
        o = a[0]   
        for i in a: 
            if i < o:
                o = i
        b.append(o) 
        a.remove(o)
    return b #return your final answer
```

Comment: why are you using `a` when the function signature contains all it needs?

Comment: yeah i noticed that right before I read your comment lol.  I guess I need to make x =num1, y=num2, z=num3.  I am still not quite sure how to get the function to return an answer like that is provided in the examples of the instructions i posted though.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
import bisect
def rank3(x,y,z, ascending=True):
    if x <= y:
        ret = [x, y]
    else:
        ret = [y, x]
    pz = bisect.bisect(ret, z)
    ret.insert(pz, z)
    if not ascending:
        ret = ret[::-1] # or use ret.reverse()
    return tuple(ret)
```

In case you do not even want to use `bisect`, do a little while loop until you find an element in `ret` which is greater than `z` (hint, use `enumerate`)

However, this is shorter and more pythonic

```
def rank3(x,y,z, ascending=True):
    return tuple(sorted((x,y,z), reverse=not ascending))
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without the sorted function.  I have to do everything manually.  Any further help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all - try to find answer in built-in python functions.
And after all write your own.
For your example python have a good method sorted(). And you can reverse your list/tuple by reverse() method.

Comment: I am not allowed to call the sorted function.  I'm only allowed to make my own up.  I am not quite sure how to get the function to return an answer like that is provided in the examples of the instructions i posted.

Comment: As i can see you want to return sorted tuple and if flag is False you return reverse sorted tuple. Am i right?